# « Je t'ai manqué » : a-t-il deux interprétations ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

Je crois que peux dire « J'ai manqué le train » ou « Je l'ai manqué » pour signifier que j'étais en retard. Je peux aussi dire, « Je t'ai manqué » pour signifier « *you missed me* » dans le sens sentimental.

Si je veux dire « *I missed you* » dans le sens que j'ai failli te rencontrer, est-ce que c'est correct de dire « Je t'ai manqué » ou est-ce que ça veut forcement dire « *you missed me* » dans le sens sentimental ?

Comment: oui, on le dit souvent.

Comment: Selon mon expérience de l'oralité (en france), pour un rendez-vous, on dit plutôt _je t'ai raté_, ou _je t'ai loupé_ ; j'entends peu l'expression _je t'ai manqué_ dans quelque sens que ce soit, sauf peut être pour des appels téléphoniques.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En plus du sens d'absence, d'*être en moins* dans la présence à l'autre :

> Durant mon absence, je *t'ai manqué*?

ou de *faire défaut* :

> J'étais aussi à Paris, *je t'ai manqué* (nous ne nous sommes pas rencontrés)

il y a le sens de *ne pas réussir* :

> Je t'ai visé et *je t'ai manqué*

et de *s'abstenir* :

> Ce spectacle?, *je l'ai manqué*! (volontairement je n'y suis pas allé)